# How restore a cluster with tablespaces in postgresql windows 10

Tags: postgresql, tar, tablespace, pitr

I created two tablespaces one for tables and the second for indexes. I use postgresql V 14.5 (win 10).

With pg_basebackup of the cluster, I get 5 files :

- base.tar
- pg_wal.tar
- 21511.tar
- 21512.tar
- backup_manifest

However, when I restore the base.tar with the command : tar xvf .... only the cluster files are restored and I don't know where to restore the tar tablespaces.

How is the workflow to achieve the restore correctly in win 10 ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried the documentation?

Comment: You restore them to the respective tablespaces.